# WPF design & binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application. I have a custom object that contain a list. The list is a custom type of "Order", the list contains 24 items. The list contains three properties. First property "baseCurrency" (i.e. GBP) of type string, second property "orderCurrency" (i.e. JPY) of type string & the third property "calculate" of type boolean.

In my WPF application I have a grid that is split into 24 equal size squares. In each square I want a control that contains a textbox and two small icon images. I want the textbox to be bound to the two string properties for an item from my list. The two small icon images are flags. So if we have GBP & JPY the two images would be their respective flags. I also want to bind the images based on the string provided. So if GBP is selects the gbp.jpn image in my project folder - not sure how I do this?

I'm think of using a toggle button as my control that will contain the textbox and images. I hoping to bind each button to a list item. The calculate property will be bound to the toggle button IsChecked property. If IsChecked is true I want my calculate property to be true.

Is there a better control that I should be using rather than a toggle button? Is there also a better way of trying to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is so common that the **MVVM** pattern is widely used in WPF for that purposes. To get started, you may read about:

- [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) - To build your application structure
- [Data Bindings in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - To bind your data to grid in a right way
- [Data templates for controls in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - To adjust the data bound

> **There is also a post on my blog related to [working with currency in WPF application](http://developersblog.tk/currency-rate-manager-csh-wcf-wpf-mvvm/)**